# Can ReSharper 5.0 beta run tests with Gallio in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, resharper, gallio

When setting up a new machine yesterday I:

1. Installed VS2008 *without* test support (I'd rather use Gallio and ReSharper if I need to use MSTest)
2. Installed ReSharper 5.0 beta
3. Installed Gallio 3.1 update 2

ReSharper doesn't see any of my MbUnit tests - there are no unit test markers in the margin and running all tests doesn't work. Should the current versions of these bits be working together or should I go back to ReSharper 4.5 for now?

*Update:* I have also tried a "typical" VS2008 installation with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff Brown just released an update to Gallio so it should work with ReSharper 5.0 Beta: http://groups.google.com/group/gallio-dev/browse_thread/thread/7fd947efe4a8849e

Comment: I noticed that - I'll try it tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no ReSharper 5.0 test runner in Gallio yet, so it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the ASP.NET MVC stuff in ReSharper is so nice that I'm just using TestDriven.NET and Icarus to run my tests until Gallio adds support for the ReSharper test runner.

[TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/) works well for running/debugging individual tests, while Icarus works for running all tests in a solution or project.  The Icarus test runner comes with Gallio which I'm sure you already know.